# WYGWAM 2.6.3 and Image URL tags

Tags: assets, wygwam

I have an issue where I upload an image through WYGWAM 2.6.3, then using Assets 2.0.1 as a file browser, and when I view the Source it has the IMG tag in there.  I save / submit the entry, but when I view it on the live published site it has the IMG tag stripped out leaving just the URL as plain text.  There isn't any parameters to my WYGWAM custom field tag and it's just the name of the field.  The text formatting around the image shows up, it's just the IMG tag that doesn't.  Odd.

Not sure what's going on.  Any help?

Assets 2.0.1, WYGWAM 2.6.3, EE 2.5.5

**EDITS:** *Process*

I have a WYGWAM field set to Brandon's original "Basic" configuration.  WYGWAM 2.6.3, Assets 2.0.1 are being used.

1. I load the entry, click in the field to where I want to insert the image
2. Click the little picture icon, it loads Assets, I choose to upload a new image
3. I upload it
4. Choose the file in Assets, it inserts my uploaded image.
5. Next I view the source and I see the IMG tag with the SRC to a URL (that image path does load an image by itself).
6. I go and view the entry on my page and it just has the URL as plain text, tags are gone.

Those are my steps.

Comment: Hey Mitchell - are you adding your image code while in source view?  Or are you in the normal view when adding your image tag?

Comment: I'm using the WYGWAM toolbar to insert an image from Assets 2.0.1.  I click the button, upload an image, double click the image to place it, Submit the entry, and then it strips out the IMG tag on the live site.

Comment: I am going to try to reproduce this locally.  Could you update your original post with the step-by-step clicks you're using so that I am sure I am doing the same things?  Thank you!

Comment: I have a WYGWAM field set to Brandon's original "Basic" configuration.  WYGWAM 2.6.3, Assets 2.0.1 are being used.  I load the entry, click in the field to where I want to insert the image, click the little picture icon, it loads Assets, I choose to upload a new image, I upload it, choose the file in Assets, it inserts my uploaded image.  Next I view the source and I see the IMG tag with the SRC to a URL (that image path does load an image by itself).  I go and view the entry on my page and it just has the URL as plain text, tags are gone.  Those are my steps.

Comment: Hey Mitchell - you mention that you are viewing the source - are you exiting out of the source view before submitting your post?  I am having trouble reproducing this either way.   Is this a pure Wygwam custom field, or a Matrix? Any other details that might help?

Comment: It's a regular WYGWAM field in a regular channel entry.  Nothing special about the field, it uses Brandon's "Basic" configuration. Should I try it without Assets 2.0.2 being used as the file manager? What can I do to help show the problem better? @LisaWess

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this but failing miserably.  Is this a site that may be accessible to me? If so, would you consider sending over Superadmin details to support@pixelandtonic.com so I can get a better look?  Please reference this EESE post so that I know what the details refer to.  Thanks!

Comment: I emailed you the credentials Lisa.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've responded, Mitchell.  I had trouble reproducing this on your site in a simplified setup.  Details in email. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue with Channel Videos.  I'll consider this response from Lisa Wess as an answer in that it isn't a WYGWAM issue.  Thank you Lisa for helping out.

Comment: My pleasure, Mitchell!

Comment: Turns out it was user error on my end.  Reminder: don't forget to enable image URL's in custom fields under Channel preferences.  #facepalm